# Forwarding domain to an existing website

Tags: custom-domain

Is there any way to forward an SFMC domain to an existing url?

The domain from which I am sending emails is example.com. I want to redirect this domain to example12.com. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to submit a [Sender Authentication Package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) form and have the SAP updated to your new domain. Note that this usually comes at a cost.